# Camel JPA query parameters not being seen

Tags: spring, jpa, apache-camel

I am currently having an issue getting Camel to see my JPA query parameters for the current code.  I have tested that the registry can access the parameters in my map, but my jpa endpoint in the pollenrich is saying it cannot locate my parameters.

Versions:

```
 JBoss Fuse: 6.2.1.redhat-084
 Camel: 6.2.1.redhat-084
 Hibernate: 4.2.20.Final-redhat-1
 Hibernate jpa 2.0 API: 1.0.1.Final
```

Camel Route:

```
    from("direct:routeUpdates").routeId("RouteUpdates")
        .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "${body}")
        .beanRef("ParameterManager", "setupQueryParameters").id("DetermineNamedQueryParameters")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                Registry registry = exchange.getContext().getRegistry();
                Map<String, Object> map = registry.lookupByNameAndType("params", Map.class);
                System.out.println("driverId: " + map.get("driverId"));
                System.out.println("statusDate: " + map.get("statusDate"));
            }
        })
        .pollEnrich("jpa:" + RouteEntity.class.getName() + "?consumeDelete=false&delay=3000&consumeLockEntity=false&consumer.namedQuery=findRouteByDriverIdAndDate&consumer.parameters=#params", new RouteStatusAggregationStrategy()).id("EnrichWithPreviousRouteEntityData")
        .to("jpa:" + RouteEntity.class.getName() + "?usePersist=false&flushOnSend=true&joinTransaction=true").id("PersistRouteEntity");
```

Spring Context:

```
<bean id="PackageCarStatusRoute" class="com.ups.ops.cipe.internal.route.PackageCarStatusRoute">
</bean>

<bean id="ParameterManager" class="com.ups.ops.cipe.internal.parameter.RouteEntityNamedQueryParameterManager">
    <property name="params" ref="params" />
</bean>

<util:map id="params" key-type="java.lang.String">
    <entry key="driverId" value="0049124"/>
    <entry key="statusDate" value="Wed Apr 13 21:02:17 EDT 2016"/>
</util:map>
```

JPA Entity:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(RouteEntityId.class)
@Table(name = "RouteStatus")
@NamedQuery(name = "findRouteByDriverIdAndDate", query = "SELECT r FROM RouteEntity r WHERE r.driverId = :driverId AND r.statusDate = :statusDate")
public class RouteEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DriverId", updatable = false, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String driverId;

    @Id
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "StatusDate", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Date statusDate;

    @Column(name = "DriverName", length = 5-)
    private String driverName;

    //removed setters getters and other variables for brevity
}
```

Log:

```
driverId: 0049124
statusDate: Wed Apr 13 21:02:17 EDT 2016
2016-04-13 17:02:22,057 [ity.RouteEntity] WARN  JpaConsumer                    - Consumer Consumer[jpa://com.ups.ops.cipe.external.route.entity.RouteEntity?consumeDelete=false&consumeLockEntity=falseconsumer.namedQuery%3DfindRouteByDriverIdAndDate&consumer.parameters=%23params&delay=3000] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[jpa://com.ups.ops.cipe.external.route.entity.RouteEntity?consumeDelete=false&consumeLockEntity=falseconsumer.namedQuery%3DfindRouteByDriverIdAndDate&consumer.parameters=%23params&delay=3000]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [driverId]]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [driverId]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaConsumer.configureParameters(JpaConsumer.java:488)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaConsumer$1.doInTransaction(JpaConsumer.java:101)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaConsumer.poll(JpaConsumer.java:92)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [driverId]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:466)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:436)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:371)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: What Hibernate and Camel/camel-jpa versions are you using?

Comment: @rpozarickij  I just updated my example with some version information.  Please let me know if you need any additional info

Comment: @Mattew By the way there's an "&" missing in pollEnrich between consumeLockEntity and consumer.namedQuery, "consumeLockEntity=falseconsumer.namedQuery=findRouteByDriverIdAndDate". Was this exact URI used to reproduce the exception? Because I'm not sure how the Camel JPA component was able to pick up the name of the named query.

Comment: @rpozarickij  Just double checked my code looks like its a copy paste issue I will fix my post.

Comment: What does .beanRef("ParameterManager", "setupQueryParameters") do?  Does it do anything to #params map?

Comment: @rpozarickij  Yes typically that bean would adjust the #params map so it could by dynamic for each call, but I commented out the logic in it while debugging

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce any problems with the provided code snippets. The same exception could only be produced after manually renaming parameters from #params map, otherwise everything worked fine. Did you try to isolate the problem? Say, create new route and use pollEnrich URI in a `from` part?

Comment: @rpozarickij hmm no I have not tried that yet.  I was avoid using the from URI since I wanted this to be used as an enrichment process for the data.  I will try testing it in a from and seeing if I can move it over.

Comment: @rpozarickij Thank you for all the help, but It turned out to be a messed up spring schema location.  Once I fixed the Util xmlns to have a schema location as well suddenly I could find parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured it out.  The long story short is to make sure I don't mess up my spring schema location tag.  I had:

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
```

I had forgotten to add this to schema location:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
```

The end spring header was looking like this for anyone with the same issue:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```