# camel-jpa query - select with parameters

Tags: apache-camel, camel-jpa

I'm trying to use the jpa component to select by id that i get from the header.
I found an example in documentation that uses the native select query:

```
from("direct:query").to("jpa://org.apache.camel.examples.MultiSteps?query=
select o from org.apache.camel.examples.MultiSteps o where o.step = 1");
```

I tried to replace the "1" constant with ${header.id}:

```
from("direct:query").to("jpa://org.apache.camel.examples.MultiSteps?query=
select o from org.apache.camel.examples.MultiSteps o where o.step = ${header.id}");
```

It doesn't seem to work, i get:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '{'
```

Maybe there is another way to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this, based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836518/how-to-pass-namedquery-parameters-in-apache-camel-jpa-by-header):

Just needed to use toD instead of to:

```
from("direct:query").toD("jpa://org.apache.camel.examples.MultiSteps?query=
select o from org.apache.camel.examples.MultiSteps o where o.step = ${header.id}");
```